# squashTA falied to configure plugin parameters (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I've just install squashTA and I try to do this tutorial

https://sites.google.com/a/henix.fr/wiki-squash-ta/tutorials/tuto-3-how-to-test-a-web-application-with-database-checks-with-squash-ta-and-selenium

but when I try to run I have this message in console output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - [name of my company]m:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [integration-test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to configure plugin parameters for: org.squashtest.ta:squash-ta-maven-plugin:1.6.0-RELEASE



 Cause: Cannot find setter nor field in   org.squashtest.ta.commons.exporter.html.HtmlSuiteResultExporter for 'exportAttached'
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
 [INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 20 10:53:10 CEST 2013
 [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/59M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there anybody, who had the same problem as my?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. During "run configurations" I choosed wrong option in "Maven Runtime". In my eclipse, it should be option "embedded", while I choosed "external" from my local drive.

Answer (score -1):

For your information, Squash TA is now called Squash AUTOM and is based on an open source orchestrator called OpenTestFactory
More information:

- https://www.squashtest.com/product-squash-autom?lang=en
- http://opentestfactory.org/

Comment: It's 3 years old so it can change, also this doesn't answer the question